# Attempting to find the sum of an array using divide and conquer using JavaScript but is outputting undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Traditionally, I know in most cases divide and conquer algorithms divide the parent array into two subarrays in order to perform the desired operation and then merge it all back together. In my case, I am attempting to divide the parent array into **three subarrays** rather than two and merging it all back together in order to determine the sum of all integers in the array. However, during testing, it outputs as undefined. I assume this is due to **mid1** and **mid2** somehow not being properly defined or something is wrong with my recursion.

My Code (Compiled with Node.js):

```js
function divideAndConquerSum(a) {
  return divideAndConquerSumMerge(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

function divideAndConquerSumMerge(a, low, high) {
  if (high == low) return a[low];

  var mid1 = low + (high - low) / 3;
  var mid2 = mid1 + (high - low) / 3;

  return (
    divideAndConquerSum(a, low, mid1 - 1) +
    divideAndConquerSum(a, mid1 + 1, mid2 - 1) +
    divideAndConquerSum(a, mid2 + 1, high)
  );
}

let a = [1, 5, -1, 4];
console.log(divideAndConquerSum(a));
```

The expected output should be 9, but it returns undefined instead.
Edit: No longer has overloaded functions. Now gives a stack overflow error.

Comment: There are 2 function with same name `divideAndConquerSum` ...

Comment: You are calling the second function, not the first. Even if you did you would also get a stack overflow.

Comment: You have a severe misunderstanding on how function overloading is done in JavaScript. You can't have two functions that have the same name; you're effectively overriding the first function definition by immediately re-declaring it in the subsequent lines.

Comment: `low + ( high - low ) / 3` will gives floating point number.

Comment: @esqew My apologies, I realized I didn't post the updated code without the overloaded functions, just fixed it but now it gives the error Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded.

Comment: Your code no longer prints `undefined`. It now throws a stack overflow error.

Comment: @Spectric is this due to my recursion?

Comment: Why don't you just do a liner summation `array.reduce((a, c) => a + c)`? Why divide and conquer algorithm?

Comment: @h-sifat I'm just trying to get more familiar with divide and conquer algorithms.